# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined bp-plupload.min.js

Tags: javascript, errors, buddypress

Getting this error in Chrome dev tools after upgrade to Wordpress 5.5 few days ago. The error appears when users try to upload an avatar in Buddypress profile and are unable to.

I have disabled most of my plugins except Buddypress and PMPro but error persists.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at addFile (bp-plupload.min.js?ver=6.1.0:1)
    at c (embed.min.js:11)
    at Function.cc (embed.min.js:11)
    at initialize (bp-plupload.min.js?ver=6.1.0:1)
    at i.h.View (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
    at i.constructor (wp-backbone.min.js?ver=5.4.2:2)
    at i [as constructor] (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
    at new i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
    at Object.uploadProgress (avatar.min.js?ver=6.1.0:1)
    at p (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
```

Comment: I'd try 6.2.0 if you haven't already - that's only a few weeks old, so might have 5.5 compatibility fixes - but otherwise I think you'll need to report this to BuddyPress directly unless you know how their views work yourself.

Comment: In case it helps, here's [the unminified version of that code](https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/6.1.0/src/bp-core/js/bp-plupload.js#L396). The `this.views` will be undefined.

Comment: Hi @rup. I did some more digging and found the issue apparently was caused by a javascript in header from Termly.io cookie consent banner - it's not a plugin but an application. They are looking into it but I have no resolution yet.